# Why are some project files randomly showing up as ignored after installing .gitignore plugin for PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I added the .gitignore plugin to PhpStorm a few weeks ago and out of the blue one of my project files turns grey in the project bar.

This happens randomly like one or two files a day on average. They weren't being ignored before but now they are although I haven't changed anything in the `.gitignore` file or any other Git configuration file.

Has this happened to anyone else? Has anyone figured out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone figured out what's going on?

Please complain to **.gitignore plugin author(s)** -- there are quite few tickets about this on their [Issue Tracker already](https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore/issues).